# Get substring from cell after last space in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets

I would like to get last substring from cell in google Sheets. I mean everything after last space. 
For example:
'*Viatti V-130 Strada Asimmetrico 215/60 R16 **95V***' - get 95V
'*Viatti Vettore Brina V-525 205/70 R15C **106/104R***' - get 106/104R

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Try `=REGEXREPLACE(<cell>, "^.* ([^ ]*)$", "$1")`

Comment: This is good, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "([^ ]+)$")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also try-

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ", REPT(" ",100)),100))
```

If you want to apply to full column then use below array formula.

```
=ArrayFormula(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A," ", REPT(" ",100)),100)))
```